# Why are there 2 variance formulas equal?

Tags: statistics

I have found two separate definitions for variance, listed below. Could you please explain why they are equivalent?

i) Variance of y $= \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(y_i - \mu)^2 $

ii) Variance of y $= \displaystyle \left(\sum_{i=1}^n p_i y_i^2\right) - \mu^2$

Comment: sum_{i=1}^{n} is supposed to be sigma notation with i=1,2....n

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: $(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab$ and $\mu_y = \sum_i p_iy_i$.

Comment: I expanded the first equation but I cannot get it to look like the second one.

Comment: We must have seen this question a few times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n p_i(y_i - \mu)^2 & = \sum_i p_i(y_i^2 - 2 \mu y_i + \mu^2) \\[12pt]
& = \left(\sum_i p_i y_i^2\right) -2\mu\left(\sum_i p_i y_i\right) + n\mu^2 \\[12pt]
& = \left(\sum_i p_i y_i^2\right) -2\mu(n\mu) + n \mu^2 
\end{align}
$$
Now do some routine algebraic simplifications.

Comment: How come $p_i$ did not distribute to 2$uy_i$?

Comment: Typo.  Fixed. ${{{}}}$